# Create a grand total row in sql server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm writing a query where in there should be a total row at the end of the table that gives the sum of the `closed` , `open`, `reassigned columns`.

I'm able to make a pivot, but unable to know how to place a row in the end. I've searched online but mostly found solutions for creating a column and a row or just column. I'm into Dev, dunno much about the databases. below is my pivot. please let me know how can i do this.

```
select *
from 
(
  select [case owner] as AGENT, [final status]
  from StatusTable
) src
pivot
(
  count([final status])
  for [final status] in ([CLOSED], [OPEN], [REASSIGNED])
) piv
```

The current output is as below image

[image]

And here I want an extra row as shown below.

```
TOTAL | 2 | 8 | 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. What are the columns you have in the DB, and how shall this "total row" be appended? Also I assume that you just want a query/view, not actually append some row to the table.

Comment: Hi @Lucero, 
I've only 2 columns `case owner` and `final status` and in the final status I've 3 categories as `closed, open, reassigned` and i'm making a pivot by taking the count of these, and under the `AGENT` i need a row named `total` and in the following columns the sum of the columns. I've updated my question (added an image) of my DB output.

Comment: Have you had a look at the `ROLLUP` keyword. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to concat rowsets with identical columns:

```
with ctePivot as (
    select *
    from 
    (
      select [case owner] as AGENT, [final status]
      from StatusTable
    ) src
    pivot
    (
      count([final status])
      for [final status] in ([CLOSED], [OPEN], [REASSIGNED])
    ) piv
)
select * from ctePivot
union all
select 'TOTAL', sum([CLOSED]), sum([OPEN]), sum([REASSIGNED]) from ctePivot
```

Or the simpler variant with only a `GROUP BY ROLLUP`:

```
select ISNULL([case owner], 'TOTAL') as AGENT, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN [final status]='CLOSED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [CLOSED],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [final status]='OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [OPEN],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [final status]='REASSIGNED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [REASSIGNED]
    from StatusTable
    GROUP BY ROLLUP ([case owner]);
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch, just as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `agent` is a key field, you can aggregate on that and use `GROUP BY ROLLUP()`:

```
select coalesce(piv.agent,'Grand Total') agent
    ,sum(piv.closed) closed
    ,sum(piv.open) open
    ,sum(piv.reassigned) reassigned
from 
(
  select [case owner] as AGENT, [final status]
  from StatusTable
) src
pivot
(
  count([final status])
  for [final status] in ([CLOSED], [OPEN], [REASSIGNED])
) piv
group by rollup(piv.agent)
```

Comment: You should avoid the non-ISO legacy syntax of `ROLLUP`; MS writes: [This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you write your query as a group by instead of a pivot, you can use `with rollup` to get your total row. E.g.:

```
select
  [AGENT] = case when grouping([case owner])=1 then 'TOTAL' else [case owner] end,
  [CLOSED] = sum(case when [final status] = 'CLOSED' then 1 else 0 end),
  [OPEN] = sum(case when [final status] = 'OPEN' then 1 else 0 end),
  [REASSIGNED] = sum(case when [final status] = 'REASSIGNED' then 1 else 0 end)
from StatusTable
group by [case owner]
with rollup
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0bb5/8/0

Comment: Same as for Bacon Bits, you should avoid the non-ISO syntax. See my comment in his answer.